# when a library updates, should I recompile the program

Tags: c++, shared-libraries

If a shared library written in C++ updates (only add some new class member functions), should I recompile the whole program ?

How about I add some public or private data members?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is a shared library, linked dynamically with your main program, no you don't, except if you updated the headers shared between your main app and the library.

Object size might have been updated and if you use static allocations on your main program, that could create strange issues (new object size will overflow) :

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  MyClass list[12];

  return 0;
}
```

Changing object size (by adding members typically) of MyClass on a dynamic library will be a serious problem!

Comment: So, as you concluded yourself, in some cases you **do** have to re-compile.

Answer (score 1):

There are two keywords you should do further reading into: **Source compatibility**, which means that your program will still compile after updating the library, and **binary compatibility**, which means that your compiled program will still run without problems after updating the library.

Most major libraries (such as `glibc` or `libpng`) stay binary-compatible for long version ranges (usually all releases of a major version are binary compatible), and almost never break source compatibility.

There are automated tools to test binary and source compatibility (such as [this one](http://ispras.linuxbase.org/index.php/ABI_compliance_checker)).

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers to this question: No ***and*** yes.

If the library only have a minor update, or if the new functionality is added in a backward-compatible way, then you should not need to do anything. Unless you want to use the new functions of course, then you have to modify your code and recompile it.

On the other hand, if the library have made some changes that are *not* backwards compatible, then you *might* have to at least relink your project. However, the operating system may keep the old versions around if you install such a backwards-incompatible library, so your application may then use the old version and you would not have to do anything.